# iOS CBCentralManager not reconnecting

Tags: objective-c, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I connect from the phone to another device that is bonded using the UUID of that device and the method

```
- (NSArray *)retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:(NSArray *)identifiers
```

from a CBCentralManager object. I do this automatically when the application starts. Everything works good, I can send and receive data with the peripheral I connected.

Then, if I got out of range I got disconnected from the device. When I get back in range, the bluetooth automatically connects to the bonded device, but my CBCentralManager does not. So I have to force the connection by clicking on a button and retrieving connected peripherals again. 
This is pretty annoying so I was wondering, is there any method that gets called when a previously connected device gets connected again? Or any device, not necessarily one that was connected, as I have the UUID.

For more details I'm using a singleton class called `BluetoothHelper` that instantiates when the app starts and there I have the main `CBCentralManager` object `@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager *bluetoothManager;` . I initialize it by:

```
self.bluetoothManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@"randomCentralManagerId" }];
```

in the Singleton's initialization. Then, as you can see above, I try to connect to the device after receiving the central manager state.

```
-(void)startScanning{

    NSString *uuidStr = @"some string i have stored";
    NSUUID *identifier = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:uuidStr];

    NSArray *connectedDevices = [self.bluetoothManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers: @[identifier]];

    if( connectedDevices.count != 0 ){

       NSLog(@"Discovered connected devices");
       self.peripheral = [connectedDevices objectAtIndex:0];
       [self.bluetoothManager connectPeripheral:self.peripheral options:nil];
    }
}



-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{

    if( central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn ){
        return;
    }

    if( central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn ){

        [self performSelector:@selector(startScanning) withObject:nil afterDelay: 0.5];
    }

    if( central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized){
        NSLog(@"Unathorized");
    }
}
```

The singleton class is initialized in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.bluetoothHelper = [BluetoothHelper getInstance];
}
```

Comment: You need to detect the disconnection in `didDisconnectPeripheral` and issue another `connectPeripheral`

Comment: I can detect when the device gets disconnected via `didDisconnectPeripheral` and I can try to use `connectPeripheral` there again to try to reconnect, but that won't solve the situation. The only case it solves it's the one to quickly reconnect, if the device got in sight very fast. If the device gets disconnected for 1 minute, this won't solve anything.

Comment: It should. A connect can be pending for any length of time and it will complete when the peripheral is next seen. You will need to specify the Bluetooth background mode if you want the connection to complete when the app isn't in the foreground.

Comment: I'll double check and come with an answer tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure that didn't work because that was what I was trying until now.

Comment: Here is a sample project that reconnects to a BLE peripheral in the background - https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: I did that for my project too, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, I don't fully understand your project, what should deviceInfoUUID be?

Comment: In my example `deviceInfoUUID`  is simply the UUID of the "well-known" device information service - If your peripheral exposes another service that you are interested in you should substitute that.  My example uses device information because most peripherals will advertise this service and it makes the example pretty generic

Comment: Ok, got it. And it seems to work properly. I'll check what my issues are.

Comment: The bug in my code was the fact that I was using `queue:nil`, so I had to replace that with `queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)`, but I can't really figure out why. Also, I had to replace `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector
             withObject:(id)anArgument
             afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay` because of this.

Comment: Generally, `performSelector` should be replaced with GCD code anyway

Comment: you should post an answer :). thanks.